# SQL Server query for SSRS report

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a table like this:

```
period    balance
-----------------
1         100
1         200
2         300
2         400  
3         400
3         500
```

I need to show this in a SSRS report; I would like to calculate sum if max period as column maximum, then sum based on the second max which is 2

```
3      2       1
-------------------
900    700     300
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to sort the periods by the sum value of each period?

If so, the easiest way is to simply sum your data by period.

```
SELECT period, SUM(balance) as periodBalance GROUP BY period
```

This will give you

```
period periodBalance
     1 300
     2 700
     3 900
```

Them in SSRS use a matrix and set the column group to group on period.
finally set the column group sort to periodBalance Z-A assuming you want to see the largest periodBalance first. If you just want to see the periods in reverse order then just set the sort to period Z-A

Comment: Thanks ALAN for the solution . But I am having one problem because I like to show on first two period in the report and then avg of first two then avg of first four.If it is only showing all period then your solution is best. Thanks

Comment: @Baljit - the solution above solves the problem outlined in your question.  If you have another question, or your question is more detailed, can you update the question with more inputs and expected outputs?